# What language(s) i have to use to make a success or an error situation for PHP mail form?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, email

I've got a PHP mail form which is already coded :

[image: PHP Mail Form]

And I would like to appear a banner i coded using CSS and jQuery, if the form succeed to send a mail, or not :

[image: Success]

I would like to know what language could I use to make it happens ? What are your advices ?

Here is my html code for the form :

```
<form id="my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method=POST action=formmail.php>
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="formmail">


<!-- PSEUDO -->

<p>

    <h3>
        PSEUDO
        <font class="color-red">
        * :
        </font>
        <span class="padding1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="pseudo" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></p><br>


<!-- EMAIL -->

    <p> 
         EMAIL
         <font class="color-red">
             * :
         </font>
         <span class="your-email padding1"><input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></p><br>

   <!-- MOTO -->

    <p>
        QUOTE
        <font class="color-red">
        * :
        </font>

    <span class="moto padding1"><input type="moto" class="form-control" name="moto" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p><br>



  <!-- LINK OF THE GIF -->  

<p>
    LINK OF THE GIF
    <font class="color-red">
    * :
    </font>
     <span class="link-url padding1"><input type="link_url" class="form-control" name="link_url" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p><br>


  <!-- RECAPTCHA -->  
    <div align="center">
    <p><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LehFQoTAAAAAMHlOs6vgktrCdFo485AoHwmp9Cp"></div></p><br><h3>


    <!-- SUBMIT -->

<p><input type="image" src="img/submitbutton.png" value="send"/><img class="ajax-loader" src="http://s584101063.onlinehome.fr/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Envoi en cours ..." style="visibility: hidden;"></p></div>


</div>
</form>
```

Here is my PHP :

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
    {
        //form submitted

        //check if other form details are correct

        //verify captcha
        $recaptcha_secret = "MY_SECRET_RECAPTCHA";
        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        if($response["success"] === true)
        {

            Header("Location: MY_WEBSITE");





            $TO = "MY_MAIL";

$subject = "Submission";

$h = "From: " . $_POST['email'];
 $pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $link_url = $_POST['link_url'];
 $moto = $_POST['moto'];

$HTTP_POST_VARS = $_POST;


$message = "Pseudo : " . $pseudo . "\n\n " . "Email : " . $email . " \n\n" . "Text : " . $moto . "\n\n " . "URL du GIF : " . $link_url;

mail($TO, $subject, $message, $h);








        }



        else
        {
            $result
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to spammers who wish to abuse your code in order to send emails with viagra and canadian pharmacies. You should look into sanitizing user input.

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: @skrilled the recaptcha will help

Comment: @skrilled : thanks for the advice, i'm beggining

Comment: @Dagon I would like to make an event (if the mail is sent or not), and if it does, my banner appears, but I'm beginning and I don't know how to make it happens

Comment: @Dagon help is a small understatement. I used to work as a spammer, and captchas are like 0.0001 cents a piece to have solved via an API by a guy in India. While it's certainly not as ideal as no captcha to a spammer, good IP reputation is all that truly matters to deliver-ability :p

Comment: If you want to know how to make a response, `mail()` returns a boolean

Comment: @skrilled best tip to stop form spam?

Comment: To stop automated programs you can add an input field with display:none; or inside of a div with display none. 99% of the bots I've dealt with are too stupid to know the field doesn't appear as they don't actively render and look at the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VERY basic idea:

```
$test=mail($TO, $subject, $message, $h);

if($test){
echo 'EmAIL WORK';
}else{
echo 'EmAIL Fail';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : The Dagon's answer works very well, but my question was not clear, here is what I found to do what I wanted :

Thanks Dagon, but it was not really what I expected to do,
I found how to do it, it works :)

```
<?php  
if(isset($_GET['id']) AND $_GET['id']==2) {  

  echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 

    echo ' 
    $("#success-bar").css("display", "inline");
    $("#success-bar").addClass("animated bounceInDown")

    $("#success-bar").one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", 

    function(){

        $("#success-bar").removeClass("animated bounceInDown")

        $( "#close2" ).click(function() {

        $("#success-bar").addClass("animated bounceInUp")
        $("#success-bar").hide()


        $("#success-bar").one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", 

    function(){

$("#success-bar").addClass("animated bounceInDown")

        });

        });

        });';

echo '</script>';   


} 

elseif(isset($_GET['id']) AND $_GET['id']==3) {

    echo 'FALSE';

}

?>
```

Comment: ok but you're assuming the mail is sent without checking. as your for is using POST, i dont see where the get variables you check are evencoming from

Comment: It is checked by a header location in the php mail which redirect to the id :)

Comment: According to the captcha if it is ok or not of course (if it is ok currently the mail is sent)

Comment: no you attempt to send it, that's not the same as checking it is actually sent.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm beginning and currently I'm not really good in English, that's why it was complicated to make a question which could be relevant...